# Where did my self learner badge go?

Tags: support, badges

When I logged on to Meta SO a few minutes ago, a brown message said I have earned a "Self Learner Badge". But when I look at my badges, it's not there.

Where did it go?

Comment: As a self learner you have to figure that out yourself.

Comment: @lance: lol, bet you are the Wizard from Oz ... not sure whether I'm the Lion, Scarecrow, Tin Man; definitely I'm not Dorothy.

Comment: Then you've discovered the secret, "Follow the Yellow Brick Road".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Answered your own question with score
>   of 3 or more

As far as I can tell, you don't have any answers that qualify - so you shouldn't have earned it in the first place.

Is it possible someone downvoted a a self-answer and its score dropped from 3 to 2? (Even so, you're not supposed to be able to un-earn badges).

Comment: There's only one self answer I can see and that's at a score of -2. Maybe when all the downvotes went AWOL the badge was issued and later rescinded?

Comment: @ Jon B and Martin Smith:  I've marked Jon's answer and upvoted both Jon's answer and Martin's comment because they both sound like plausible reasons; thank you both for researching this.